# Several TLS certs for the same host nginxinc kubernetes ingress

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I'm playing with k8s and Nginx ingress controller
(https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/).

I have a hostname test.example.com, that handles HTTPS connections, using two certificates (RSA and GOST) signed for the same name.

Is there a proper way of terminating those TLS connections, using Nginx Ingress? Or am I better of using an external load-balancer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the answer was actually in the discussion on GitHub page
https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/issues/1899#issuecomment-905952871

There is no direct support, but one can try a workaround with server-snippets:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: cafe-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.org/server-snippets: |
      ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/secrets/default-second-cafe-secret; # namespace-name
      ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/secrets/default-second-cafe-secret; # namespace-name
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - cafe.example.com
    secretName: cafe-secret
  - hosts: # this part is needed so that the IC gets the second-cafe-secret from k8s API and store it on the file system at /etc/nginx/secrets/namespace-name
    - random-workaround-host 
    secretName: second-cafe-secret
  rules:
  - host: cafe.example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

First leats clear out what `terminating` is:

> SSL termination refers to the process of decrypting encrypted traffic before passing it along to a web server.

There are other ways as well as you mentioned like using external `LoadBalancer` but sine `Nginx` is a `LoadBalancer` there is no need to add another external `LoadBalancer`

#### Keep it simple

- Keep it simple, and you'll have fewer problems in the long run.
- Using [nginx-controller](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/) is a suitable way to accomplish it.
- Adding more "tools" will require you to maintain them as well which increases the complexicity.

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: I don't need just a loadbalncer for web service, I need to solve a specific problem (that is solvable with raw Nginx) with nginx-ingress in kubernetes environment. That is to terminate TLS connections for clients that use different cipher-suits on one hostname (or server directive maybe a better word).

Comment: Still, its the same concept, it doesn't matter what kind of certificate each client is using, the main goal is to keep it simple, and using Nginx you can resolve it and you can support multiple certificates type. There is no need to add another layer (LB)